# Import and SUM chosen (from drop-down) column to Sheet1 from Sheet2

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, import

What formula I can use in cell C2 to import one column from sheet 2 using a drop-down list?

Here's [the document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gqsb9foYeB8rwJabu3rAfbZhhwmO3A7HycZ0cuBeiYc/edit#gid=1064603638).

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: sheet is private - share it

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(HLOOKUP(C1, 'LB dinamic'!A1:H, 
 {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'LB dinamic'!"&
 ADDRESS(2,                      MATCH(C1, 'LB dinamic'!A1:1, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS('LB dinamic'!A:A), MATCH(C1, 'LB dinamic'!A1:1, 0), 4)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('LB dinamic'!A1:M), "where Col1='"&C1&"'", 0))
```

[image: 0]